# Static properties on a Laravel model class

Tags: php, laravel, class, design-patterns, model

I'm trying to create a standard index() method for most of my controllers that combines search, pagination, and sorting into one retrieve all listings functionality.  I'm using a trait for those controllers which contains an index method, and that method uses some static properties defined on the associated model to know which columns to search and so on.  For example, my User.php contains:

```
   /**
     * @var array
     */
    public static $searchableColumns = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'title',
        'email'
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public static $searchableRelations = [
        'groups' => ['searchOn' => 'name']
    ];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public static $defaultOrderBy = 'name';
```

My issue is that...this just doesn't feel right.  Every other property on the class is a protected instance variable, e..g:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'email',
        ...
];
```

Is declaring static properties on a Model bad practice? If so, where should I define something like this?

Comment: In my non expert opinion that's perfectly fine.  On a large project I could imagine abstract classes for groups of models with the same fields but if you're not defining the same thing over and over again in the models then just leave them right where they are.

Comment: You could always make them protected and the return them with a static method?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider introducing an interface instead of static properties.

```
interface SearchableModel {

  public static function searchableColumns(): array;

  public static function searchableRelations(): array;

  public static function defaultOrderBy(): string;
}
```

And implement it like so

```
class User implements SearchableModel {

  public static function searchableColumns(): array {
    return [
      'name',
      'username',
      'title',
      'email'
    ];
  }

  public static function searchableRelations(): array {
    return [
      'groups' => ['searchOn' => 'name']
    ];
  }

  public static function defaultOrderBy(): string {
    return 'name';
  }
}
```

This solution looks similar to your approach but feels a bit cleaner in my opinion.